# Magento2 How to add footer menu an additional column

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, footer

I am using the Luma for default temple - i know i can edit the column already there in my default XML file - how do i go about copying my current footer from my magento1.9 to magento2 footer?  my current footer has 4 columns

Answer (score 1):

best is to use the widgets by selecting CMS footer links from the drop-down and create a CMS with your footer information.
to get the columns next to each other - use

```
<div class="links">
```